Understanding representation of boolean formulas in binary strings
We are given boolean formulas with common conventions such as

operators are $\neg ,\land ,\lor$,
operands have form $x_i$, for $i\in\mathbb{N}$, etc.

There are some ways to convert a certain boolean formula $\phi$ to the binary string $\langle\phi\rangle\in\{0,1\}^*$, so satisfiable $\langle\phi\rangle$'s are selected to construct $$\text{$SAT$ = $\{\langle\phi\rangle$: $\phi$ is a satisfiable boolean formula}\}.$$ According to the definition of $$\overline{SAT}=\{0,1\}^*-SAT=\{\langle\phi\rangle:\text{ $\phi$ is an unsatisfiable boolean formula}\},$$ it means that an arbitrary string, say, $w\in\{0,1\}^*$ is a binary representation of a boolean formula $\phi$. How to show that $\{0,1\}^*$ is the set of all boolean formula encodes?
IMO, our encoding way may only map the set of boolean formulas to a subset of $\{0,1\}^*$, so there is a $w\in\{0,1\}^*$ is not a boolean formula encode.
I think that this question can be extended to representation of circuit, graph, and so on, in binary strings.

This depends on the chosen encoding, but in common representations of formulas by strings, it is not true that every string is a code of a formula. Strictly speaking,
$$\begin{align*}
\overline{\mathrm{SAT}}={}&\{\langle\phi\rangle:\text{$\phi$ is an unsatisfiable Boolean formula}\}\\
&\cup\{w:\text{$w$ is not a code of a Boolean formula}\}.
\end{align*}$$
This distinction is, however, usually ignored, because the set of codes of Boolean formulas is efficiently computable (in $\mathrm P$, or even in uniform $\mathrm{TC}^0$, for the most common representations). Thus,
$$\{\langle\phi\rangle:\text{$\phi$ is an unsatisfiable Boolean formula}\}$$
has the same complexity as the true $\overline{\mathrm{SAT}}$ (i.e., the two sets are many-one reducible to each other).

By the way, Arora and Barak, on page 69, say that "every string $x\in{0, 1}^∗$ represents some TM (denoted by $M_x$), and every TM is represented by inﬁnitely many strings." Is the authors' intention also similar to yours, i.e. ignored strings is not a code of a TM, in the former statement?

How could their intention be the same when their conclusion is the exact opposite? If you set up the encoding such that every string represents a TM, then every string represents a TM. If you don't, it doesn't. As I wrote, it all depends on the encoding. But defining the encoding so that every string encodes one of the target objects requires the encoding to be defined in an artificial way (e.g., you say something like "a string that is a formula according to the usual definition represents that formula, and all other strings represent the formula $\bot$", which, in particular, makes the ...

... encoding not bijective). This is perhaps easier to do for TM as there is no natural conventional representation for TM anyway. But Boolean formulas already are finite strings defined in the usual inductive way, so making all strings represent Boolean formulas requires you to do something unnatural.

There is another problem with these artificial schemes for making all strings represent something: they break inclusion. For example, every first-order $L$-formula is also an $L'$-formula for any language $L'$ such that $L\subseteq L'$. But if you set up the encoding so that every string already represent an $L$-formula, then it is impossible to represent $L'$ -formulas in a compatible way. Likewise, e.g., for encoding of simple graphs and graphs with self-loops. Or, for encoding of integers and encoding of rationals.

Thank master for your careful explanation. I forgot the "artificial way" encoding, forcing unconventional strings represent an object. The explanation about side-effect of artificial schemes breaking inclusion is also great, which I have never thought before.
